# Adding vertex where point intersect in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, vertices, intersect

How do I add a vertex to a line or polygon  where a point feature intersects it?

I am using ArcGIS Desktop.

Comment: Have you looked at the Intersect tool?

Answer (score 0):

If it's a line you can use break line at point and merge the features with dissolve. The attribute to dissolve back can be an autoincrement you place on a new field you create before the break. The point doesn't have to be exactly on top of the line. Use the distance you want.

Polygon could get a bit tricky though. Can we see what type of data you have?